# Show that $\mathbb{R}^2/∼$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, equivalence-relations, quotient-spaces

**Question**: Let $∼$ be the equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by ($x_1,x_2)∼ (y_1,y_2)$ if and only if $x_2 = y_2$. Show that the identiﬁcation space $\mathbb{R}^2/∼$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

I have tried to define a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2/∼ \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x,y)=y$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}$. Then $f$ is clearly a bijection.

My trouble is to show $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous. I think $f$ is a projection map, so it is continuous, am I right?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the topology on $\mathbb{R}^2 / \sim$?

Comment: @mathworker21 Not really, the question has not mentioned the topology, I guess just the quotient topology

Comment: That $f$ is continuous (with quotient topology on $\mathbb{R}^2 / \sim$) comes from the continuity of $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $(x,y) \mapsto y$, which induces a continuous map on the quotient. That $f$ is a bijection is clear. That $f^{-1}$ is continuous can be shown by explicitly describing it as a composition of maps $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 / \sim$, where the first is $t \mapsto (0 , t)$ and the second is the quotient map, both of which maps are continuous.

Comment: @Point nice! you're missing a parenthesis somewhere though

Comment: @mathworker21 Thanks! I have tried to fix the paranthesis problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $[y]$ denote the equivalence class of any point $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, according to $\sim$. That is, $[y] = \{(x,y) : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Now let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Then $f^{-1}(U) = \{[y] : y \in U\}$ and this set is open in $\mathbb{R}^2/ \sim$ by the definition of quotient toplogy, since if $\pi : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 / \sim$ given by $\pi(x,y) = [y]$ is the quotient map, then $\pi^{-1}(f^{-1}(U)) = \mathbb{R}\times U$, which is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

That $f^{-1}$ is continuous means that if $W$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2/ \sim$, then $f(W)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. So fix such $W$ and note that $\pi^{-1}(W) = \mathbb{R}\times W$ must be open in $\mathbb{R}^2$, so $W$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. But $W = f(W)$, so we're done.